# Selecting multiple rows relative to active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a VBA macro to

- select two rows above the activecell
- then autofill the two selected rows down one.

`ActiveCell.EntireRow.Offset(-2, 0).Select` selects the entire row (2 rows above the active cell), but I want it to select the row below this one as well. A recorded macro:

```
Range("A143").Activate
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Rows("142:144"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Instead of absolute values for rows (rows 142:144), I want it to take the two selected rows above instead.

Comment: Do you want to auto fill the two rows above with the selected cell's row contets?

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help

```
Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim r2 As Excel.Range

Set r = ActiveCell.EntireRow
Set r2 = ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).EntireRow.Resize(2)

r2.Value = r.Value   **** OR **** r.Copy r2
```